# TilesConfigurer is deprecated ?? How I use tile2.2 in spring MVC 3.1?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, frameworks, apache-tiles

I try to integrate Spring MVC 3.1 with Apache Tile2.2 but I found this error

```
Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed
```

so I search it in google and I found in Apache Tile2 structure had change or deprecated but spring mvc 3.1 still use old structure. (Someone said We must modify the class or etc.)

These are my lib I used:

```
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
tiles-el-2.2.2.jar
tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
tiles-template-2.2.2.jar
```

adn spring mvc

```
org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.0.M1.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar
```

Anyone know how I fix this ? It will be useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you import from org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3 package you will not get any depricated issue but if you import from org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2 it is depreciated. I solved the issue by changing imports. 
Configuration class

```
package mum.waa;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;

@Configuration
public class TilesConfiguration{

public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer()
{
    final TilesConfigurer configurer = new TilesConfigurer();
    configurer.setDefinitions(new String[] { "WEB-INF/tiles.xml" });
    configurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
    return configurer;
}

@Bean
public TilesViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
    final TilesViewResolver resolver = new TilesViewResolver();
    resolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
    return resolver;
}

}
```

Dependencies

```
        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Tiles -->
```

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> solution:
>
> This is not error by deprecated it's about jar file that didn't right version.
>
> I solved by find right jar to my web application
>
> this is my jar

```
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-bean-collections-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar
commons-digester-2.1.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.3.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.3.jar
tiles-api-2.2.2.jar
tiles-core-2.2.2.jar
tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar
tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar
```

> For some people get lost like me, Mart